# Java read file: list invalid data

Tags: java, text-files

I want to list all invalid data from a text file that looks like:

1299

dwhie

1237

213

kmn

Anything smaller than 1000 or not number are invalid. My code looks like:

```
    String score;
    int count=0;
    int number;
    TextIO.readFile("scores.txt");
    System.out.println("reading the file now...");

    while (!TextIO.eof())
    {
        count ++;
        score = TextIO.getln();
        number = Integer.parseInt(score);
    if (number < 1000)
    {
        System.out.println(score);
    }
```

However it failed at listing all nonnumber data. Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What's the error you're getting that you can't solve?

Comment: The error msg says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "dwhie"

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it:

```
try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(score);
    if (number >= 1000) {
        // number is valid, skip
        continue;
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // not a number; fall through
}
System.out.println(score);
```

Or you can let it loop naturally and duplicate the print statement:

```
try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(score);
    if (number < 1000) {
        System.out.println(score);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println(score);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! But when I run the code, nothing comes up in the output. Do you know what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 3):

If `score` is not a number then it will not be able to convert to an integer and will thrown an Exception.  You will need to catch this exception

```
try {
    number = Integer.parseInt(score);
    if (number < 1000)
    {
       System.out.println(score);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println ("not a number");
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! But when I run the code, nothing comes up in the output. Do you know what's wrong with this?

Comment: Are you sure that the file is opened?  Try printing out each line as debug information